# Heatmap With Custom Data Cannot Display anything

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

Hello I'm trying to create a heat map with my own data that will be loaded via a API request however. I have not been able to do so. I have seen other people getting data using a function that randomly generated data but not with my formatted data. I do not know what is going wrong or what I am missing. If anyone can point out what is wrong with the code bellow. Thank you!

https://jsfiddle.net/4o8f5qmp/2/

```
var test = Highcharts.chart('container',{
    chart: {
  type: 'heatmap',
  margin: [60, 10, 80, 50]
},


title: {
    text: 'Highcharts extended heat map',
   align: 'left',
  x: 40
},

subtitle: {
  text: 'Temperature variation by day and hour through 2013',
  align: 'left',
  x: 40
},

 xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime'
},

yAxis: {
  title: {
      text: null
  },
  labels: {
      format: '{value}'
  },
  minPadding: 0,
  maxPadding: 0,
  startOnTick: false,
  endOnTick: false,
  tickWidth: 1,
  reversed: true
},

colorAxis: {
  stops: [
      [0, '#3060cf'],
      [0.5, '#fffbbc'],
      [0.9, '#c4463a'],
      [1, '#c4463a']
  ],
  min: -15,
  max: 25,
  startOnTick: false,
  endOnTick: false,
  labels: {
      format: '{value}℃'
  }
},

series: [{
  borderWidth: 0,
  nullColor: '#EFEFEF',
  colsize: 168* 36e5, // one hour
  tooltip: {
      headerFormat: 'Temperature<br/>',
      pointFormat: '{point.x:%e %b, %Y} {point.y}:00: <b>{point.value} ℃</b>'
  },
  data: (function(){
    var data = []
    rawData.forEach( item=> {
    var splitedDateTime = item.PollTimeStamp.split('T');
    var time = splitedDateTime[1].substring(0,splitedDateTime[1].length - 2);
    time = time+'00';
    
    var tempArray = [splitedDateTime[0],time,item.VarValue]
    data.push(tempArray)
  })
  /* console.log(data) */
  return data 
  }()),
    turboThreshold: Number.MAX_VALUE // #3404, remove after 4.0.5 release
}]

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is Highcharts error #14 in a console: https://assets.highcharts.com/errors/14/

You can not use strings as x and y values, you need to adapt to the data format required by Highcharts. You can use categorical axis type to display the labels in the way you want. Example:

```
const xCategories = [];
const yCategories = [];
var data = [];

rawData.forEach(item => {
    var splitedDateTime = item.PollTimeStamp.split('T');
    var time = splitedDateTime[1].substring(0, splitedDateTime[1].length - 2);
    time = time + '00';

    const matchedXCat = xCategories.find(cat => cat === splitedDateTime[0]);
    const matchedYCat = xCategories.find(cat => cat === time);
    let x;
    let y;

    if (matchedXCat) {
        x = xCategories.indexOf(matchedXCat);
    } else {
        xCategories.push(splitedDateTime[0]);
        x = xCategories.length - 1;
    }

    if (matchedYCat) {
        y = yCategories.indexOf(matchedYCat);
    } else {
        yCategories.push(time);
        y = yCategories.length - 1;
    }

    var tempArray = [x, y, item.VarValue];

    data.push(tempArray)
})
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ckjodw01/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.heatmap.data

Comment: Cheers for that mate.